# How to add new class file to group in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, file, cocoa-touch

I have noticed that now whenever I do command-N to create a new Cocoa Touch class in my project, it keeps adding the file outside of the project in the file tree:

[image]

The behavior I remember (I haven't touched this project in a few weeks), is that whenever I create a new class it automatically places it in the group that you are currently working in, something like this:

[image]

Is there any way to restore this behavior? Creating a new plain .swift file seems to give you the choice of picking the group, but creating a new Cocoa Touch class does not. Regardless, I don't remember having to pick the group at all, it "just worked".

Please let me know if you need any more info. Xcode v6.3.2/6.4 on El Capitan

EDIT: I have tested further, and it seems the correct behavior is observed when adding new swift files and playgrounds, but not when adding new Cocoa Touch Classes.

EDIT 2: Here is photos of the file creation process and how it isn't working:

Step 1) Command-N, select new Cocoa Touch Class

Step 2) Name class like usual:

[image]

Step 3) Here is where the problem seems to lie. It gives me the option of placing where I want my files to be saved to on the disk, but it isn't allowing me to choose a group or target:

[image]

I also discovered that clicking the `Options` button on the bottom seems to bring up the group and target selection pane, but they are grayed out and cannot be interacted with:

[image]

EDIT 3: Just tested same action with Xcode 7 and Xcode 7 gets it right. Seems to be some kind of bug with Xcode 6.3.2/6.4

Comment: may be  clicking on the group once and do command-N will help that?

Comment: @anishparajuli No luck with that, unfortunately

Comment: sorry it didnot help with you..but always good with me

Comment: @dcgoss I had the same issue. After installing Xcode 7, the problem has gone. I don't know why !?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem in Xcode 6.4. 
Just create a new Cocoa Touch class in your project and after that, **delete the reference to this file(delete->Remove Reference)**. After that go to File->Add File to your project, find your file in project folder. There you will be able to selecte target project in select the Group.
I think it will help you :)

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:** Command + N to create a new class

[image]

**Step 2:** Name your class

[image]

**Step 3:** Specify the group where you'd like the class to go

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce that third step. I can reproduce it most of the other types of files, but not the Cocoa Touch classes. I will add a picture to the question to show further

Comment: Just added some additional pictures to the bottom reproducing the issue.

Comment: Have you tried nuking derived data, restarting Xcode, and/or rebooting?

Comment: Have tried all 3. Also just added another edit: everything seems to work fine in Xcode 7. Seems to be an issue with 6.3.2